# How to print column offset within each matching line in grep

Tags: unix, grep

By passing -o -n to grep I can output all matching parts of a pattern within a file, and the line number on which each match was found.

How can I also print the column offset within that line at which the pattern was found?

Comment: Just for clarity sake, by column offset you mean character offset into the line/string, right?

Comment: Yes that right, character offset into the line.

Comment: Vim `set grepprg` :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think I was able to mimic the same thing you're doing with awk. Referencing the AWK manual:

http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html

Here's what my file looks like:

```
this,is,a,test,line
this, ,a,test,line,with,the,second,field,blank
this, is,another,test,line,with,a,blank,in,the,second,field,but,the,field,isnt,blank
this, ,is,another,line,with,a,blank,second,field
```

And here's the command I ran:

```
awk '{regex = "test"; where = match($0, regex); print "REGEX: ",where," on line ",NR}' test
```

And the output:

```
REGEX:  11  on line  1
REGEX:  10  on line  2
REGEX:  18  on line  3
REGEX:  0  on line  4
```

I did this quick and dirty, but I'm hoping it helps enough to get you where you need to be.

Comment: you may need a while loop? otherwise you just find the first match per line.